# Samba ACL deny change permissions

Tags: permissions, redhat, samba, samba4

I just created a Samba share under Redhat 7, with sssd as authentication provider and the use of ACLs.
Here is my config:

```
[global]
    realm = domain.local
    workgroup = domain
    security = ads
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    log level = 3
    debug pid = true
    max log size = 0        
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    map acl inherit = yes
    store dos attributes = yes

[projects]
    path = /projects
    valid users = @grp_dep-team,@grp_dep-studenten
    writeable = yes
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
```

Here is the ACL on one directory:

```
# file: dep01/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::rwx
group:root:rwx
group:dl_dep01_rw:rwx
group:dl_dep01_ro:r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:root:rwx
default:group:dl_dep01_rw:rwx
default:group:dl_dep01_ro:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Everything works fine and as expected.

The only problem is, that dl_dep01_rw has "Full access". I want to deny "Take Ownership" and "Change Permissions".

Is this even possible?

***EDIT1***
I just added the last 3 values to my global section and removed the force-configuration. I can remove the "change permission" permission, but it has no effect:
The user still can modify file and folder permissions.

kind regards

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_POSIX_ACLs and https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs

Comment: I just edited my configuration (see above) but is has no effect ...